# Close form override

Tags: c#, winforms, overriding

I’ve created a winform application with lots of forms, (in mdi and dialog)
but every time a close a form it stays in the memory,
so I would like to use de .Dispose() option.

but I don’t want to add this code to ALL of the forms,
I just want to place one code that’s activates on a FormClose command,
can i use en override.onFormClose command?

and where in the application do I  put this code,
I tried it at the MDI form,  but without success

Thanks,
Bram

ps
i'm using DevExpress components

Comment: `Dispose` is already overridden in your form, if you look at your form.Designer.cs file. How come your forms are staying in memory after closing ?

Comment: use `using` statement to dispose form.

Comment: [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) FTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call GC.Collect() and the forms are still in memory, then it is because there is a reference held to them somewhere.

You need to trace all references and make sure they are being released.

Answer (score 0):

Craete a separate base class, implement your dispose method, and then inherit all forms from this class